# Need to prove this modular arithmetic theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

if $2^7 \equiv 2 \mod n$ and $3^7 \equiv 3 \mod n$, then $a^7 \equiv a \mod n$.

I know Chines remainder and Eulers theorem but can't figure out how to proof this.

Comment: What are the quantifiers for $a$ and $n$? All $a$? Perhaps using the definition of modular arithmetic might help. (ie. writing $2^6=2+kn$, etc)

Comment: Hint:  $2^7-2=126$ and $3^7-3=2184$ and $\gcd(126,2184)=42$.

Comment: Thus n divides 42. If n = 42 I can show that the order of every element divides 6, thus x^7 = x mod 42. Then it follows x^7=x mod n?

Comment: Just show directly (using FLT) that $2\mid a^7 - a$ and $3 \mid a^7 - a$. Clearly $7 \mid a^7 - a$ and so $42 \mid a^7 - a$, which since $n \mid 42$ resolves the problem.